Как починить мету в Yandex "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)." в Next.js
Сайт запущен и исправно работает, но часто вижу если делать site:example.com что мета ставится "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).", хотя при переходе на сайт все хорошо работает.
Несколько раз ловили в консоли ошибку "ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 601 failed." и "Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://react.dev/errors/423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.", но понять почему она возникает не получилось. Получилось повторить если обновлять сайт много раз с CTRL+F5 и то только на Firefox браузере.
Next.js 14.2.3, output standalone, DevOps смотрел сервер, говорит все нормально, next запущен в Docker, отдается через Nginx proxy. Ошибок на сервере в Next.js и Nginx нет (в nginx пару раз было 499 на чанки, но вроде все исправно работало)

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Такая же проблема. Заметил что такой баг происходит и на офф сайте nextjs.org.
Я пока прикрутил этот плагин webpack-retry-chunk-load-plugin
webpack: (
    config,
) => {
    config.plugins.push(new RetryChunkLoadPlugin({
        maxRetries: 10,
    }))
    return config
},

Проблема теперь не возникает в mozilla, буду наблюдать что покажет yandex
